# How to get matrix values using Surge

Tags: swift, matrix

I am using the Surge framework to do matrix operations.
https://github.com/mattt/Surge

I want to access the values of the matrix by indices.  I don't know how to do this using Surge.

```
//create arbitrary matrix, this works fine
var matrix : Matrix<Double> = Matrix<Double>([[4,7], [2,6]])

// I want to get the 4 but this doesn't work..
let rm11 = resultMatrix.subscript(row:1,col:1)
```

Anyone know how to access the values of my created matrix?  Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by 'doesn't work'? Is there a compiler error? A runtime error? An incorrect value returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift, the name `subscript` does not act like a normal function (indeed you can see that it is not declared with the `func` keyword). Instead, a struct/enum/class with a `subscript` member can be used with bracket syntax. That is to say, your code should probably look like this:

```
//create arbitrary matrix
var matrix : Matrix<Double> = Matrix<Double>([[4,7], [2,6]])

// get the 4
let rm11 = resultMatrix[1, 1]
```

Read more about subscripts [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Subscripts.html).

Comment: I'm getting a assertion failed: file /Users/yuep/Downloads/Surge-master/Source/Matrix.swift, line 58 error do you know what's going on?  I am using your bracket syntax.

Comment: Nevermind I think the first element start at 0 not 1 is the problem.

Comment: Would you like to update the comments within the code ? 

Comment: @ManuelV.Battan Updated!